# Calculating point coordinates on a line in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, html5-canvas, cubic-bezier

In this [draggable ChartJS demo](https://chrispahm.github.io/chartjs-plugin-dragdata/) is it possible to derive a set of interpolated coordinates along one of the curves that ChartJS plots?

```js
    var options = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            fill: true,
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 25
          },
          {
            label: '# of Points',
            data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
            fill: true,
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 25
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            min: 0,
            max: 20
          }
        },
        onHover: function(e) {
          const point = e.chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(e, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, false)
          if (point.length) e.native.target.style.cursor = 'grab'
          else e.native.target.style.cursor = 'default'
        },
        plugins: {
          dragData: {
            round: 1,
            showTooltip: true,
            onDragStart: function(e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
              // console.log(e)
            },
            onDrag: function(e, datasetIndex, index, value) {              
              e.target.style.cursor = 'grabbing'
              // console.log(e, datasetIndex, index, value)
            },
            onDragEnd: function(e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
              e.target.style.cursor = 'default' 
              // console.log(datasetIndex, index, value)
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
    window.test = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chart.js Drag Data Points Plugin</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/chartjs-plugin-dragdata.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    canvas {
      background-color: #eee;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>



<canvas id="chartJSContainer" style="height: 90%; width: 90%;"></canvas>
```

The demo plots an array of 5 values.

```
data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
```

Is there a way to use Javascript produce an array of 10 y values where the x coordinates are evenly spaced along the curve?

So for example if the canvas width is 200px, then the x coordinates would increment in values of `20px`, and the y value would be the corresponding point on the bezier curve.

[I looked through the ChartJS API documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html), and I don't see an API for the bezier curve function for each plot exposed, but perhaps there is a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending for what you want to use this, an easy workaround/solution is:

- fill in the `labels` property the correct amount of units need, for example `["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Green"]`
- fill the array with some empty values*(neatly spaced, you could do this also with code)*, to match the size of the `labels`-array, like so `[7, null, 11, null,  5 , null,  8, null,   3, null,  7]`
- and use the `spanGaps: true` property so that chartjs will connect the points.

Like this **chartjs**, fills in the gaps and you can space out the chart without manually calculating any extra values.

**Small Demo:**

```js
var options = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Green"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Points',
          data: [7, null, 11, null,  5 , null,  8, null,   3, null,  7],
          fill: true,
          tension: 0.4,
          borderWidth: 1,
          pointHitRadius: 25,
          spanGaps: true
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          min: 0,
          max: 20
        }
      },
    }
  }

  let ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
    html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartJSContainer" style="height: 180px; width: 500px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow!  Genius!  I love it!  That's really cool that you can do that!  I was hoping there would be a way to call a method on the chartjs API that would "Interpolate" in the real values for the `null` instances, so that these values could be used in other chart libraries ...

Comment: I created a feature request with ChartJS building on your example.  https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11629

Comment: Great to hear it works for you. If it solved your initial question, please consider accepting my answer with the green checkmark, under the voting arrows. Thank you.