# Obtaining the coordinate of a null value when using spanGaps with ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, chart.js, html5-canvas

I'm wondering if ChartJS exposes an API for plugins that allows us to obtain the coordinate of a `null` point that has been "Spanned" by ChartJS?

[For example as illustrated in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760054/calculating-point-coordinates-on-a-line-in-chartjs) ChartJS enables smooth curves through `null` points when settings `spanGaps` to `true`.

So we could have data points like this.

```
data: [7, null, 11, null,  5 , null,  8, null,   3, null,  7],
```

Corresponding to these labels.

```
["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Green"],
```

Is there a way ( Perhaps via the Plugin API ) to get the values of the nulls?

So for a given quadratic curve that chart JS draws for:

```
data: [7, null, 11, null,  5 , null,  8, null,   3, null,  7],
```

We could call for example:

```
const arr = ChartJSPluginAPI.deriveNulls(data);
```

And get something like:

```
data: [7, 8, 11, 6, 5 , 6,  8, 4, 3, 5, 7],
```

Thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the interpolated values *as they are calculated by chart.js* is
not trivial, because chart.js performs the interpolation in graphical mode
only, so we have to get the graphical values of the existing points
for the relevant [datasets meta](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getsortedvisibledatasetmetas),
perform the interpolation, and then get back to the real space, using
the y-axis [scaling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/classes/Scale.html#getvalueforpixel).
This is however safer than trying to emulate the interpolation mathematically in real space.

The first thing in finding the intermediate values is to identify the
functions used by chart.js to interpolate all the values of the curves;
there are three functions: `_steppedInterpolation` for
[stepped](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#stepped)
line charts, `_bezierInterpolation` if there is a `tension` option set,
and the default linear interpolation as `_pointInLine`.

```js
const _bezierInterpolation = Chart.helpers._bezierInterpolation,
    _steppedInterpolation = Chart.helpers._steppedInterpolation,
    _pointInLine = Chart.helpers._pointInLine;
```

Note that if modules are used, the `helpers` module needs to be imported
separately.

An important point is to perform the computation after the animation is
completed, since for instance the bezier coefficients (if bezier interpolation
was used) are constantly recomputed during the animation, and their final
values can only be obtained after the animation is
finalized. So, we implement the computation in the animation's
[`onComplete`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation-callbacks)
handler:

```js
onComplete: function({chart}){
   const datasetMetas = chart.getSortedVisibleDatasetMetas();
   for(const datasetMeta of datasetMetas){
      if(datasetMeta.type === 'line'){
         const controller = datasetMeta.controller,
            spanGaps = controller.options.spanGaps,
            dataRaw = controller._data;
         if(spanGaps && dataRaw.includes(null)){
            const gData = datasetMeta.data,
               yScale = datasetMeta.yScale,
               yValues = []; // the final result
            const tension = controller.options.tension || controller.options.elements.line.tension;
               interpolation = controller.options.stepped ? _steppedInterpolation :
                  tension ? _bezierInterpolation : _pointInLine;
            for(let i = 0; i < gData.length; i++){
               if(dataRaw[i] !== null){
                  yValues.push(dataRaw[i]);
               }
               else if(i === 0 || i ===gData.length-1){
                  yValues.push(null); // no interpolation for extreme points
               }
               else{
                  const pLeft = gData[i-1],
                     pThis = gData[i],
                     pRight = gData[i+1];
                  const xgLeft = pLeft.x, xg = pThis.x, xgRight = pRight.x,
                     frac = (xg - xgLeft) / (xgRight - xgLeft);
                  let {y: yg} = interpolation(pLeft, pRight, frac);
                  yValues.push(yScale.getValueForPixel(yg));
               }
            }
            console.log(`For dataset ${controller.index}:`, yValues);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This solution assumes the index axis is `x` and the value axis is `y`;
it should work regardless of the `type` of the `x` axis (`category`,
`linear`, `time`, etc.).

Here's a full snippet with this solution applied to the OP example.

```js
const _bezierInterpolation = Chart.helpers._bezierInterpolation,
    _steppedInterpolation = Chart.helpers._steppedInterpolation,
    _pointInLine = Chart.helpers._pointInLine;
// note: different access with modules

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Green"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [7, null, 11, null,  5 , null,  8, null,   3, null,  7],
            spanGaps: true,
            fill: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 25,
            tension: 0.4
        }]
    },
    options: {
       animation:{
            onComplete: function({chart}){
                const datesetMetas = chart.getSortedVisibleDatasetMetas();
                for(const datasetMeta of datesetMetas){
                    if(datasetMeta.type === 'line'){
                        const controller = datasetMeta.controller,
                            spanGaps = controller.options.spanGaps,
                            dataRaw = controller._data;
                        if(spanGaps && dataRaw.includes(null)){
                            const gData = datasetMeta.data,
                                yScale = datasetMeta.yScale,
                                yValues = []; // the final result
                            const tension = controller.options.tension || controller.options.elements.line.tension;
                                interpolation = controller.options.stepped ? _steppedInterpolation :
                                    tension ? _bezierInterpolation : _pointInLine;
                            for(let i = 0; i < gData.length; i++){
                                if(dataRaw[i] !== null){
                                    yValues.push(dataRaw[i]);
                                }
                                else if(i === 0 || i ===gData.length-1){
                                    yValues.push(null); // no interpolation for extreme points
                                }
                                else{
                                    const pLeft = gData[i-1],
                                        pThis = gData[i],
                                        pRight = gData[i+1];
                                    const xgLeft = pLeft.x, xg = pThis.x, xgRight = pRight.x,
                                        frac = (xg - xgLeft) / (xgRight - xgLeft);
                                    let {y: yg} = interpolation(pLeft, pRight, frac);
                                    yValues.push(yScale.getValueForPixel(yg));
                                }
                            }
                            console.log(`For dataset ${controller.index}:`, yValues);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                min: 0,
                max: 20
            }
        }
    }
}

const chart = new Chart('chartJSContainer', config);
```

```html
<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" style="background-color: #eee;">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-ZwR1/gSZM3ai6vCdI+LVF1zSq/5HznD3ZSTk7kajkaj4D292NLuduDCO1c/NT8Id+jE58KYLKT7hXnbtryGmMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Chart (and options) one could calculate the points yourself. You just would have to check the chartjs code on github, too match the functions, how the lines are generated and create/find a function that gives you the points.

**Heres a crude demo:**
*(this demo just works with max one gap and *the beizer curve*, but with better math skills more is possible)*

```js
    console.clear();

    function calcBiezierCurvePoint(idx) {
      let metaData = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data;

      if (!metaData[idx].skip) {
        console.info(metaData[idx])
        return metaData[idx]
      }

      let prev = null
      let next = null
      let prevIdx = idx - 1;
      let nextIdx = idx + 1;
      while (!prev || !next) {
        if (!metaData[prevIdx].skip) {
          prev = metaData[prevIdx]
        }

        if (!metaData[nextIdx].skip) {
          next = metaData[nextIdx]
        }
      }

      console.info({ prev, next });

      let minY = Math.min(prev.y, next.y)
      let maxY = Math.max(prev.y, next.y)

      let minX = Math.min(prev.x, next.x)
      let maxX = Math.max(prev.x, next.x)

      let deltaX = maxX - minX;
      let deltaY = maxY - minY;

      let _c = calcBiezier({
        x: (prev.cp2x - minX) / deltaX,
        y: (prev.cp2y - minY) / deltaY
      }, {
        x: (next.cp1x - minX) / deltaX,
        y: (next.cp1y - minY) / deltaY
      }, deltaY / deltaX);

      console.info({ _c }, deltaY / deltaX)

      console.info((_c.x * deltaX) + minX, (_c.y / deltaX * deltaY) + minY)
      return { x: (_c.x * deltaX) / 2 + minX, y: (_c.y * deltaY) / 2 + minY }

    }

    // P = (1-t)P1 + tP2
    function calcBiezier(p1, p2, t) {
      let x = (1 - t) * p1.x + p2.x
      let y = (1 - t) * p1.y + p2.y
      return { x, y }
    }

    var options = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Green"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: '# of Points',
            data: [7, null, 11, null, 5, null, 8, null, 3, null, 7],
            fill: true,
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 25,
            spanGaps: true
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            min: 0,
            max: 20
          }
        },
      }
    }

    let ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
    let chart = new Chart(ctx, options);


    setTimeout(() => {
      let points = [
        calcBiezierCurvePoint(0),
        calcBiezierCurvePoint(1),
        calcBiezierCurvePoint(2),
        calcBiezierCurvePoint(3),
        calcBiezierCurvePoint(4),
        calcBiezierCurvePoint(5),
      ];

      for (let p of points) {
        console.info({ p })
        ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 10, 10)
        ctx.fillRect(p.cp1x, p.cp1y, 5, 5)
        ctx.fillRect(p.cp2x, p.cp2y, 5, 5)
      }

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y)
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(points[0].cp2x, points[0].cp2y, points[2].cp1x, points[2].cp1y,
        points[2].x, points[2].y);
      ctx.stroke();

    }, 2000);
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartJSContainer" style="height: 180px; width: 500px;"></canvas>
```